# HP Product Research on Activity Log

Tags: driver, activity-monitor, malware

I'm seeing an item on my activity monitor called 'HP Product Research.'

I assume it's associated with some HP Printer drivers that I no long need, and have have removed, but this tracker keeps hanging around.

Any ideas on how to get rid of this tracker?

Comment: Can't you `Inspect` in Activity Monitor, then `Open Files and Ports`, and delete the files mentioned there?

Comment: Try System Preferences > Users & Groups > (your user) > Login Items tab. Click the lock in the lower-left to authenticate, then click the HP item in the list and click the - (minus) button to remove it.

Comment: A combination of the two seemed to work. I think there are some remnant files somewhere, but the app is at least not functioning now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo may find this app here:

```
/Library/Printers/hp/Utilities/HPPU Plugins/ProductImprovementStudy.hptask/Contents/Helpers/HP Customer Participation.app
```

Just move it to the trash.

Comment: In my case the name was `'/Library/Printers/hp/Utilities/HPPU Plugins/ProductImprovementStudy.hptask/Contents/Helpers/HP Product Research Manager.app'`

Comment: WARNING: Do you know if there is a stack trace to show what originally caused the call to this program?  simply removing the program may still cause some /var/log/system.log errors if its tried to be called?

Answer (score 1):

There's an official way to remove it: Run HP Customer Participation.app from the HP application folder. There's a checkbox to 'opt out' of product research.

Comment: Tried that. It does not work.

Comment: Yes, this does not work as HP Customer Participation.app is not visible

Answer (score 0):

Macintosh HD

Library | Application Support | Hewlett-Packard | Customer Participation

HP Product Research.app and other files are in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check your "System Preferences" -> "Users" -> "Login Items" and look at what exactly caused the call to "HP Product Research".

[image]

You should also view the "Activity Monitor" and view the specifics of what other "Open Files and Ports" are involved with the process.  Be careful ... it maybe isn't smart even to remove other files in the "/Library/Printers/hp/Frameworks/" directory other then the .app?

[image]

its also very helpful to search your "console" and system.log file for "hp" just to see whats going on before removal... (just to see what is going on) (dont remove anything outside of "/Library/Printers/hp" and do a reboot just to make sure everything is "safe" after?  Here is a picture of what a console "system.log" looks like for "HP" (special note: these "errors" are most likely caused by closing the process down while its trying to startup again...

[image]

It can be interesting to save all the details and "sample" the "HP Product Research" process and see the full "call graph" of the process?

:)